# Unwanted uninstall with apt-get install

Tags: command-line, apt

I accidentally pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> I had this line in command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-
```

I tried to auto-complete with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and instead I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I ended up with a lot of stuff uninstalled, is this standard behavior with install option of apt-get command? Can somebody explain what happened? I did not get any warning or confirmation, see below uninstall.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-

Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-lame' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-esd' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-dvswitch' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'libgstreamer0.10-dev' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-schroedinger' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-doc' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-really-bad' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-cutter' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-doc' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-farsight' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-alsa' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-doc' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-audiosource' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-xvid' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-tools' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-qapt' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-chromaprint' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-x' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-gnonlin' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-gconf' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-videosource' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-doc' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-doc' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-audiosink' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-videosink' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-x264' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-visualization' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-packagekit' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'libgstreamer0.10-0' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-doc' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-nice' for regex 'gstreamer0.10'
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-really-bad' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' instead of 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-farsight'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' instead of 'gstreamer0.10-schroedinger'
Package 'gstreamer0.10-xvid' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-lame' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-x264' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-packagekit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-gconf' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-nice' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libgstreamer0.10-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-chromaprint' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-dvswitch' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-gnonlin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-gnonlin-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-cutter' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-qapt' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer0.10-esd' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  clementine gstreamer-tools gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-x iptux
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 36.3 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 221799 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing clementine (1.2.3+dfsg-4) ...
Removing gstreamer-tools (0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64 (0.10.36-2) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs:amd64 (0.10.36-2) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64 (0.10.31-3+nmu4ubuntu2~gcc5.1) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64 (0.10.36-2) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64 (0.10.19-2.1ubuntu3) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-tools (0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-x:amd64 (0.10.36-2) ...
Removing iptux (0.6.1-1) ...
Removing libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64 (0.10.36-2) ...
Removing libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64 (0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-get install gstreamer0.10-
```

is equivalent to

```
apt-get remove gstreamer0.10
```

The `-` at the end of the package name instructs apt-get to remove the package instead of installing it. 
From the manpage of apt-get:

> **install pkg(s)**
>
>   (...)
>   If a hyphen (-) is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be removed if it is currently installed. Similarly a plus sign (+) can be used to designate a package to install. These latter features may be used to override decisions made by apt-get's conflict resolution system.

Comment: There is no package with name`gstreamer0.10-`, it did not install anything new, it just uninstalled and without prompting for confirmation like `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  Answer modified.

Comment: Thank you, I totally overlooked this part in the man page,  I finally found it in install section too after you pointed it out.